# Jasperreport library version 6.17.0 produced error with PDF export

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I recompiled our application based on Jasperreport library and got an error, calling PDF export

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:190)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForName(JRClassLoader.java:148)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRSingletonCache.createInstance(JRSingletonCache.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRSingletonCache.getCachedInstance(JRSingletonCache.java:77)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.getPdfProducerFactory(JRPdfExporter.java:735)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.createPdfProducer(JRPdfExporter.java:806)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.initExport(JRPdfExporter.java:704)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:665)
at org.wgsoftpro.reposerver.SetReport.OutputReport(SetReport.java:770)
at org.wgsoftpro.reposerver.CreateReport.run(CreateReport.java:598)
at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl$RunnableWrapper.run(AsyncContextImpl.java:602)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

It worked fine with version 6.16. I just changed 6.16 to 6.17 in pom.xml. Any suggestion will be appriciated

Comment: many thanks, good hint. Was not attentive with first try to debug. Details are in question answer

Answer (score 0):

Solved, it would be better if the new rules had been mentioned in version read.me. We replaced *default.jasperreports.propertie*s for our needs. And now the string

```
net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.producer.factory=net.sf.jasperreports.export.pdf.classic.ClassicPdfProducerFactory
```

must present in *default.jasperreports.properties* file to get the library possibility to load corresponding class.